# How to convert a file into a list then into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file with each line containing a name and some numbers for instance
John, 55 , 77, 89
Sarah, 78, 45, 67
Joe, 40, 99, 63, 89,60
I was able to convert this to a list using split(). But I can’t figure out how to turn it to a dictionary from there. I have something like [‘John’, ‘55,’ ‘77,’… etc. How do I covert this list to a dictionary and am I on the right path?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are there always 3 numbers following a name or is it variable? Please [edit] your question and post an example list.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is probably a dict comprehension.

```
nn_list = ['John', 55 , 77, 89, 'Sarah', 78, 45, 67, 'Joe', 40, 99, 63]
nn_dict = {block[0]:block[1:] for block in (nn_list[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(nn_list),4))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module and a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    result = {row[0]: row[1:]
              for row in csv.reader(f)}
```

For each row in the csv file, we build a dictionary using the first value `row[0]` as the key, and the rest of the the row, `row[1:]` as the value.